# when scaffoling ef7 i keep getting Error: Illegal character '/' (Unicode hexadecimal 002F). on command line

Tags: entity-framework

I am not sure why I keep getting this Error: `Illegal character '/' (Unicode hexadecimal 002F)` when reversing a database with EF 7 on the command line. Can someone tell me where in the string is shown below on the command line that is causing this. What is  weird if I just type dnx ef  I get the same error error.

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\SpaceRadar\src\SpaceRadar.EntityFramework>dnx ef
dbcontext scaffold  "data source=database_server;initial
catalog=DemoDb;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=*****"
EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer -a -c "DataStore" -o Model
```

Error: `Illegal character '/' (Unicode hexadecimal 002F)`

Answer (score 0):

This could be because there are comments in the project.json file, which are not supported by the JSON parser.

Comment: This was true in RC1. In RC2 and beyond json files are read using JSON.Net which does support comments.